# How to avoid re rendering using flatlist in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

I'm calling API response in useEffect initially when viewing the screen for the first time,  but the API request kept running I guess because I've reached my limit of sending requests. (I'm new to this tech).

I'm using Flatlist to display the items, my goal is to render only when the data gets updated.

Thanks in advance.

```
 useEffect(() => {
         getCategory();
    }, [data])
```

```
 const getCategory = async () => {
        setLoading(true)
        await fetch(`URL`,
            {
                headers: {
                    'x-api-key': 'API_KEY'
                }
            })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then(resJson => {
                setData(resJson)
            }).catch(e => { console.log(e, 'ERROR') })
        setLoading(false)
    }
```

Comment: Why did you put `data` in the dependency array? Remove it

Comment: It isn't clear what flat list you are referring to, but you've clearly an issue in the `useEffect` hook where the dependency is the value the effect updates. This creates a render loop, i.e. infinitely rerenders the component the effect is in. Remove `data` as a dependency ***or*** don't unconditionally update *that* state.

Answer (score 0):

I think it looks like you have added your state data as a dependency in your useEffect hook, so when your async function is called on the first render and you then setData in the async function, it will call the useEffect again and it will render again. Remove the word data in the useEffect hook and it will only render once.

Comment: how do I manage the data when it gets updated?

Comment: It needs to be deserialized to use it as a JavaScript object. Use JSON.parse() before you set it into state and you should be able to use it as a JavaScript object.